# Software for virtual desktops in Windows 7?

Tags: software-rec, desktop, virtual-desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best Virtual Desktop Manager out there for Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/261401/whats-the-best-virtual-desktop-manager-out-there-for-windows-7)

So is there an application that creates virtual desktops decently, that anyone would recommend, *except* for the sysinternals one?

Operating system is Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out [WindowsPager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/windowspager/). It works on XP, Vista and 7. [Here's](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YoJYa3BYuY8) a short video showing how this application functions on Vista. Downside: it only allows 4 Virtual Desktops.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [VirtuaWin](http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/) for years. It works on all Windows versions and allows creation of up to 20 desktops (although it says up to 9 on the website).